# How to merge one object id with same value into new array javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

i have array of object transaction join with product and user table, i want to combine id with same value so it can display two different data in 1 object

**Here's my data**

```
let test = [
  {
            TransactionId: 1, //transaction table
            username: "A", //user table
            qty: 3, //product table
            product_name: "Logitech G733",
            price: $100,
            description: "Lalalalala",
            productId: 10
},
{


            TransactionId: 2,
            username: "B",
            qty: 1,
            product_name: "Razer",
            price: $200,
            description: "Blalalala",
            productId: 12
},
{
            TransactionId: 1,
            username: "A",
            qty: 1,
            product_name: "Mousepad",
            price: $50,
            description: "This is mousepad",
            productId: 7
},
{
            TransactionId: 3,
            username: "C",
            qty: 2,
            product_name: "Headphone",
            price: $300,
            description: "This is Headphone",
            productId: 2
},
]
```

**this is the output i want**

```
let test = [
  {
            TransactionId: 1,
            username: "A",
            qty: [3, 1],
            product_name: ["Logitech G733", "Mousepad"],
            price: [$100, $50]
            description: ["Lalalalala", "This is mousepad"],
            productId: [10, 7]
},
{


            TransactionId: 2,
            username: "B",
            qty: 1,
            product_name: "Razer",
            price: $200,
            description: "Blalalala",
            productId: 12
},
{
            TransactionId: 3,
            username: "C",
            qty: 2,
            product_name: "Headphone",
            price: $300,
            description: "This is Headphone",
            productId: 2
},
]
```

i tried using reduce and Object.assign but the output only shows object with "Mousepad" not make array ["logitech G733","Mousepad"]

Comment: `$300` is not a valid JavaScript literal.

Comment: Is the username functionally dependent on the transactionId?

Comment: You've asked a question before. Any reason why you didn't give any feedback to the answers that were posted?

Comment: no its otherwise, i have sequelize model User.hasMany(Transaction) and Transaction.belongsTo(User). i'm new to node.js sorry if my explanations wrong

Comment: oh.. back then i'm new in stackoverflow and i can't give upvote because my reputation score is lower than 10 or 15 or minimum requirement to give upvote

Answer (score 1):

there should be many ways to do it, I used a map to combine the transactions and you can do whatever you need for the map after.  For example

```
const test = [
  {
              TransactionId: 1, //transaction table
              username: "A", //user table
              qty: 3, //product table
              product_name: "Logitech G733",
              price: 100,
              description: "Lalalalala",
              productId: 10
  },
  {


              TransactionId: 2,
              username: "B",
              qty: 1,
              product_name: "Razer",
              price: 200,
              description: "Blalalala",
              productId: 12
  },
  {
              TransactionId: 1,
              username: "A",
              qty: 1,
              product_name: "Mousepad",
              price: 50,
              description: "This is mousepad",
              productId: 7
  },
  {
              TransactionId: 3,
              username: "C",
              qty: 2,
              product_name: "Headphone",
              price: 300,
              description: "This is Headphone",
              productId: 2
  },
]

const tMap = new Map();

test.forEach(transation => {
  tMap.set(transation.TransactionId, { ...tMap.get(transation.TransactionId), ...transation });
})
```

If you wan to deep combined you can use some tool like lodash deep merge

```
tMap.set(transation.TransactionId, _.merge(tMap.get(transation.TransactionId), transation))
```

Then you have a map based on your tranastion Id, and you can decide what to do next.  If you wan the array back you can simple run

```
console.log(Array.from(tMap.values()));
```